# Google Places api is not showing

Tags: android, google-api

I am trying to add `places autocomplete` to my app, and hence trying to create a key. I already have a key for Google Maps. But with places, while it is showing that the api is enabled, the key is not available.

What I am doing wrong here?

[image: places api enabled]

[image: api key for places is not there]

Answer (score 0):

From the APIs & Services Credentials tab you can create a new API key that has access to the Places API or you can update one of your key's restrictions to be able to use Places API with that key. After you create or choose an API key scroll down to the bottom to API restrictions. Choose the appropriate APIs from there. If you create a new key, you might also want to put an application restriction to make your key only usable in android app.

[image: API restriction selection]